# An SVM implementation supporting non-linear kernels and multi-label on a one-vs.-rest

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, nonlinear-functions, multilabel-classification

I'm looking for a SVM implementation with support for non-linear kernels and one-vs-rest scenario, to perform a multi-label classification. Preferably, written in Python, or that I can call from Python with wrappers.

I was looking into sklearn, and there are two implementations to use SVM for classification:

[sklearn.svm.LinearSVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html)
- supports multi-label classification with a one-vs.-rest scenario, but it's based on liblinear, and therefore only supports linear kernels.

[sklearn.svm.SVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)
- based on libsvm, supports non-linear kernels, but multi-label classification is done under a one-vs.-one reduction, it trains K (K − 1) / 2 binary classifiers for a K-way multiclass problem.

More info also here:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html

Does anyone knows any other SVM implementations directly supporting multi-label classification and non-linear kernels ?

One possible solution could also be to adapt the code based on sklearn.svm.SVC, to perform One-vs-Rest, was this already attempted before?

Comment: You mean multi-class, right? multi-label is something else (each sample is labeled with more than one label)

Comment: no, I mean actually multi-label; exactly that "each sample is labeled with more than one label"

Comment: So how do you intend to use one-vs-one or one-vs-all? these are multi-class (single label) methods, not multi-label

Comment: OneVsRestClassifier: fits one classifier per class, the class is fitted against all the other classe. At prediction time, you apply each classifier (trained for each class) to decide if a given sample belongs to a class or not.

OneVsOneClassifier: fits one classifier per pair of classes, it requires K * (k - 1) / 2 classifiers, it's much slower than OneVsRestClassifier. At prediction time the class which received the most votes is selected, or every class that is classified with a probability higher than a given threshold.

Comment: I had an error on the formulation of my question, in the last sentence, just corrected it.

Comment: I don't understand how you plant to convert OneVsRest and OneVsOne which are multi class methods into multi-label methods (and I don't think you do either)

Comment: Wouldn't this be a way of performing multi-label classification: training K classifiers in a OneVsRest scenario, and predicting each class with each trained classifier ?

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning, I'm seeing this from the perspective of classifying a document (i.e. text) into different labels/topics.

Comment: @carlosdc from [scikit-learn doc.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier) on OneVsRestClassifier: "This strategy can also be used for multilabel learning, where a classifier is used to predict multiple labels for instance, by fitting on a 2-d matrix in which cell [i, j] is 1 if sample i has label j and 0 otherwise. In the multilabel learning literature, OvR is also known as the binary relevance method...", however I am not sure of OneVsOneClassifier and its usage with multilabel classification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Binary Relevance problem transformation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification) uses one-vs-rest approach for doing multi-label classification. One could easily implement SVM with non-linear kernels using [scikit-multilearn](http://scikit.ml) library. The following is the sample python code to do the same, where each row of train_y is a one-hot vector representing multiple labels (For instance, [0,0,1,0,1,0])

```
from skmultilearn.problem_transform.br import BinaryRelevance
from sklearn.svm import SVC

# Non-linear kernel
svm = SVC(kernel='rbf')
cls = BinaryRelevance(classifier=svm)

cls.fit(train_x, train_y)
predictions = cls.predict(test_x)
```

Comment: thanks Nikkhil, did not knew about https://github.com/scikit-multilearn